Python | How do I pass parameters for only 2nd argument?
Suppose I have some code like:
def sample2(a = 15, b=14):
    print("sample", a+b)

If I call sample2() I get 29, using both default values.
How can I pass an explicit value for b, but use the default value for a?

sample2(b=5)
5 being whatever you want it to be.
